# How to disable Single sign-on (SSO) with MSAL.js?

Tags: vue.js, single-sign-on, msal.js

I have a issue with MSAL and SSO. I want to disable Single sign-on (SSO) for an intranet Vue 3 SPA application. SPA is using MSAL.js. When the user first logged in an authorized account (which is user account logged to computer.), then, after sign out, if I try with an different authorized Azure AD account, the response of MSAL Popup picked up and returned  previous signed in account.
I think that it might be related to SSO.

How to disable Single sign-on (SSO) with MSAL.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While getting login, in order to disable SSO, I have used prompt option as `login` instead of `select_account` as below.

```
   await msalApp.loginPopup({
        scopes,
        prompt: 'login'
    });
```